# ASP.NETのグリッドビューであらかじめソートして表示したい

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

ASP.NETのグリッドビューであらかじめソート機能を追加する方法は沢山ありますが、
あらかじめデータ内容を特定列でソートして出す方法がわかりません。

都合がって、データソースの方ではソートしたくありません。
どのような方法がありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView.Sort`メソッドを使用します。

```
gridView.Sort("Column1,Column2,Column3", SortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました。